# Page Limitation in report output

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

is there any limitation in number of pages of a report output?

I use *iReport* for report design, I have several reports (main and subreports) in a single report.

If data available, 1 Lakh+pages are possible to generate while executing my report from application?

Comment: could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no page limit. If you're exporting the report in a specific file type (PDF, for example), check and make sure you won't exceed the size limit for that file type.